# Equation-by-equation instrumental variable regression (control function) in R

Tags: r, regression, tidyverse, broom

I want to do a **equation-by-equation instrumental variable (IV) regression** with a **control function** in **R** (using `tidyverse`  and `broom`). I want to implement this based on a grouped data frame with a dependent variable, `y`, an endogenous variable, `x`, an instrument for this endogenous variable, `z1`, and an exogeneous variable, `z2`. Following a  **Two Stage Least Squares (2SLS)** approach, I would run: (1) Regress `x` on `z1` and `z2` and (2) Regress `y` on `x`, `z2` and `v`(the residuals from (1)). For more details for this approach see: https://www.irp.wisc.edu/newsevents/workshops/appliedmicroeconometrics/participants/slides/Slides_14.pdf. Unfortunately, I am not able to run the second regression without an error (see below).

My data looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = sort(rep(seq(1, 20, 1), 5)),
  group = rep(seq(1, 4, 1), 25),
  y = runif(100),
  x = runif(100),
  z1 = runif(100),
  z2 = runif(100)
)
```

where `id` is an identifier for the observations, `group` is an identifier for the groups and the rest is defined above.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(broom)

# Nest the data frame
df_nested <- df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  nest()

# Run first stage regression and retrieve residuals
df_fit <- df_nested %>% 
  mutate(
    fit1 = map(data, ~ lm(x ~ z1 + z2, data = .x)),
    resids = map(fit1, residuals) 
  )
```

Now, I want to run the second stage regression. I've tried two things.

First:

```
df_fit %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  unnest(c(data, resids)) %>% 
  do(lm(y ~ x + z2, data = .x))
```

This produces `Error in is.data.frame(data) : object '.x' not found`.

Second:

```
df_fit %>% 
  mutate(
    fit2 = map2(data, resids, ~ lm(y ~ x + z2, data = .x))
  )
  
df_fit %>% unnest(fit2)
```

This produces: `` Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector. x Subscript has the wrong type `grouped_df< `` . If you would work with a larger data set, the second approach would even run into storage problems.

How is this done correctly?

Comment: I reformulated the question above in a more general style (with a focus on the inclusion of elements from previous regressions in the final regression). You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70287136/multi-step-regression-with-broom-and-dplyr-in-r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `broom` package is loaded but there was no `tidy` applied to the `lm` output.  In addition, the OP's code had some typos i.e. after `mutate`ing to create the `fit2`, the object 'df_fit' was not updated (`<-`), thus `df_fit %>% unnest(fit2)` wouldn't work as the column is not found

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(broom)
library(tidyr)
df_fit %>%
    ungroup %>% 
    mutate(
    fit2 = map2(data, resids, ~ tidy(lm(y ~ x + z2, data = .x))
  )) %>% 
   unnest(fit2)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 9
   group data              fit1   resids     term        estimate std.error statistic  p.value
   <dbl> <list>            <list> <list>     <chr>          <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>
 1     1 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> (Intercept)  0.357       0.126    2.82   0.00987 
 2     1 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> x           -0.0290      0.173   -0.168  0.868   
 3     1 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> z2           0.204       0.183    1.11   0.278   
 4     2 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> (Intercept)  0.470       0.139    3.38   0.00272 
 5     2 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> x            0.168       0.206    0.816  0.423   
 6     2 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> z2           0.00615     0.176    0.0350 0.972   
 7     3 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> (Intercept)  0.625       0.147    4.25   0.000325
 8     3 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> x            0.209       0.255    0.818  0.422   
 9     3 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> z2          -0.398       0.183   -2.18   0.0406  
10     4 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> (Intercept)  0.511       0.235    2.17   0.0407  
11     4 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> x            0.0468      0.247    0.189  0.851   
12     4 <tibble [25 × 5]> <lm>   <dbl [25]> z2          -0.0246      0.271   -0.0908 0.929
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved the issue.

Comment: I have a follow-up question: should't you include .y["resids"] into fit2 = map2(data, resids, ~ tidy(lm(y ~ x + z2 + .y["resids"], data = .x)) so that the residual vector is considered in the regression formula?

Comment: @timm You may have to construct the formula with `paste` or use `reformulate`.  Can you please ask as a new question